# Cell to span across all columns in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

First of all, I realise fully that this question has been asked numerous times,   but every method that I find seems to be rather out dated and/or the links that have been referred to no longer exist.

So I would like to know if there is a way to make a particular row in a JTable span across all of the columns, like one expanded cell that ignores that columns. However, I need to be able to specify whether it should span across multiple columns when I add the row, as only a few rows will need to...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please cite the approaches that were found wanting and describe briefly how each failed to meet your requirements.

Comment: @trashgod What do you mean "found wanting`? AND I did think I stated this in the first sentence...

Comment: In this context, the phrased _were found wanting_ means _failed to meet your requirements_.

Comment: You suggested you found a solution that was outdated. So if you give me the link then I can copy the solution into the posting and it will now become a current solution. Will that meet your requirements?

Comment: it's simply not supported, as in "not doable". All available (that I remember) are hacks and most require tweaking of the ui delegate. By design, that table _is not_ a general grid - which is unfortunate at times, of course. Look for third party components (maybe JIDE has something, don't remember and too hungry to search for anything right now :-)

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply everyone. It's disappointed to hear that it is not easily possible, nor really *legitimate*, but I can understand why (kinda). Please see my comment on Max's answer with regards to third party components... I think I will just take the easy option for now and make use of all the columns in such a way that the row still stands out, maybe even change it's background colour! @camickr Yes, that would have met my requirements but now I can see that I would have to go to far out of my way to use any solution for this current project atm, so it doesn't matter now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank @Max for his answer, but as I commented - I was not really prepared to pay for anything as I am going to sell the software that I am writing. Also, in general I prefer not to use third party components for various reasons, and I prefer not to even more so when the software is going to be sold. Not to mention the legal complications that some third party components may bring...

Therefore, I decided that making the rows stand out would suffice rather than merging the columns into one. I did this by overiding the cell renderer and making it so that the background colour of the cells in the desired row(s) was different to that of the normal cells. As it is, I discovered that I actually still needed all of the columns in the rows I wanted to span, so in some respects it's a good job I didn't attempt to do it but that's another story that no one needs to hear. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm) grids (i.e. `CellSpanTable` with `DefaultSpanTableModel`). [Here](http://www.jidesoft.com/images/cellspantable2.png) is how it looks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max, but because I'm software to sell I prefer not to use third party components. Plus I'm not really prepared to pay for such a thing, under any circumstance. To be honest, I don't really see the point of coding when you start to do things like that but that's a whole new topic altogether...